# Search in database and in dictionary in relation to the choice of the database, in order to satisfy two conditions

Tags: python, sql, python-3.x, dictionary, tkinter

I would like to use the contents of the combobox to search the database and dictionary. For example:

- I select John in the combobox (or any name, without specifying a certain name)
- If in the `Table1` database there is a John (in the `name` column) who is 18 years old in column `Age`
- And if in the dictionary John has `Great` in `Talent`
- Then I print "ok". The above two conditions must both be satisfied.

In the code I don't want to specify John, but any element of the combobox. I specify that John is both in the database and in the dictionary: there is both the `name` column in the database and name in the dictionary (they are two different things). I use SQLite

**PROBLEM:** The problem is that I print "ok" with whatever name I select in the combobox and this is incorrect. For example "Richard" is present in the combobox but is not present in the database, but "ok" is printed anyway and this is not correct. Also, there is a problem with the dictionary too, but I don't understand why.

I report only the part of the code useful for the resolution (without form tkinter settings and database setting). Thank you

```
from tkinter import ttk
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *
import sqlite3

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("350x200")

con = sqlite3.connect('/home/linux/Desktop/test2.db')
cursor = con.cursor()

name = {"John": {"Talent": "Great"},
        "Michael": {"Talent": "Average"},
       } #reductive example

combo1=ttk.Combobox(root, width = 22)
combo1['value'] =["John", "Richard", "Frank"] #and other 17 name
combo1.place(x=10, y=10)
combo1.set("Select")

def my_function():
    if  (cursor.execute("SELECT 1 FROM Table1 WHERE age = 18 AND name = ?", (combo1.get(),))) \
    and teams[combo1.get()]["Talent"]:
        print("ok")

btn = Button(root, text="Click", command = my_function)
btn.place(x=10, y=50)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming you mean name, not teams in my_function?
At the moment you are only checking if name['someone']['Talent'] is not empty, not whether it meets your talent criterion. I introduced the variable `talent`, you have to adapt the code to your needs.
Your issue printing always 'Ok' was already adressed [elsewhere](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74038732/check-if-the-contents-of-a-combobox-are-present-in-the-database/74038944#74038944)

```
def my_function():
    cursor.execute("SELECT 1 FROM Table1 WHERE age = 18 AND name = ?", (combo1.get(),))
    if cursor.fetchall() and (name[combo1.get()]["Talent"] == "Great"):
        print("ok")
```

Comment: Unfortunately that's not what I'm looking for. I will have a lot of variables in the dictionary and I will not be able to handle them all like in your answer. I was looking for something simpler and shorter, something like this teams [combo1.get()] ["Talent"] == "Great". So without passing talent to the function and without writing my_function ("Great"). Do you have any other ideas? Thank you

Comment: Where is "Great" coming from? Is is also an input? Do you want to be able to check for different features within your dictionary?

Comment: "Great" comes from the dictionary: it is present in the code I posted in the question. It is not an input. Yes, I just want to check inside the dictionary to see IF and WHAT text is there.

Comment: Then the solution is simply what you wrote in your first comment. I updated the answer.